# Qlabel in front of a QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel, qgridlayout

I am trying to make a `QLabel` appear **over** a `QGridLayout`, but I cannot figure how to do it.

This is a sample code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QGridLayout, QFrame, QLabel
import sys

class Foo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()



        grid_layout = QGridLayout()

        rect1 = QLabel('RECT1')
        rect1.setStyleSheet("color: green;")
        grid_layout.addWidget(rect1, 0, 1)

        rect2 = QLabel('RECT2')
        rect2.setStyleSheet("color: blue;")
        grid_layout.addWidget(rect2, 0, 2)

        self.setLayout(grid_layout)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
foo = Foo()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

For instance, I want to create another QLabel in red, and display it over them, in the center of the image:

```
red_label = QLabel('red')
red_labe.setStyleSheet("font-size:20pt; color: red;");
```

Something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to make `red_label` son of the `QWidget` for it you must pass the self parameter when the object is created. In addition to this the `QLabel` must change size when the window does, emulating the layout task for it will create a signal that will be emited in the `resizeEvent` event:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Foo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    sizeChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QSize)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        rect1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("RECT1")
        rect1.setStyleSheet("color: green;")
        grid_layout.addWidget(rect1, 0, 1)

        rect2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("RECT2")
        rect2.setStyleSheet("color: blue;")
        grid_layout.addWidget(rect2, 0, 2)

        red_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("red", self)
        red_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        red_label.setStyleSheet("font-size: 20pt; color: red;")

        self.sizeChanged.connect(red_label.resize)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.sizeChanged.emit(event.size())
        super().resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    foo = Foo()
    foo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little less elegant of a solution, but it does keep the red labeled centered as the window is resized.

```
class Foo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        grid_layout = QGridLayout()

        rect1 = QLabel('RECT1')
        rect1.setStyleSheet("color: green;")
        grid_layout.addWidget(rect1, 0, 0)

        rect2 = QLabel('RECT2')
        rect2.setStyleSheet("color: blue;")
        grid_layout.addWidget(rect2, 0, 2)


        grid_layout_two = QGridLayout()

        blank_label = QLabel()

        red_label = QLabel('red')
        red_label.setStyleSheet("font-size:20pt; color: red;")
        grid_layout_two.addWidget(blank_label, 0, 0)
        grid_layout_two.addWidget(red_label, 0, 1)
        grid_layout_two.addWidget(blank_label, 0, 2)

        grid_layout_three = QGridLayout()
        grid_layout_three.addItem(grid_layout, 0, 0)
        grid_layout_three.addItem(grid_layout_two, 0, 0)

        self.setLayout(grid_layout_three)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
foo = Foo()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Basically making three grid layouts, positioning the elements so that the red label is in the center of the other two labels but in a grid layout that is in front of the other labels layout.